# Вход содержит NaN, infinity или значение, слишком большое для dtype ('float32')

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Я применяю pdpbox к моей модели, построенная на RandomForestRegressor.
 Вот мой код

```
from pdpbox import pdp, get_dataset, info_plots
feature_names = X.columns.tolist()
pdp_1 = pdp.pdp_isolate(
model=model_1, dataset=X, model_features=feature_names, feature='col1')
fig, axes = pdp.pdp_plot(pdp_1)
```

Я получаю следующую ошибку

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')
```

Я проверила следующим образом на NAN и infinity dataframe - результат False

```
print (np.any(np.isnan(X)))
print (np.all(np.isfinite(X)))
```

Из за чего может быть ошибка?

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе вывод команды `X.info()`?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  
    RangeIndex: 63 entries, 0 to 62  
    Columns: 169 entries, sum_packs_budget to sum_sales_diff_11
    dtypes: float64(134), int64(35)
    memory usage: 83.3 KB

Comment: я думаю в вопросе стоит привести полный `error traceback`

Answer (score 0):

Решением проблемы является, удалить все `inf`.

```
X=X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
X=X.fillna(0)
```